# Xamarin.Forms drag listview item and show options?

Tags: listview, button, xamarin.forms, drag

Hy guys, 
I'm working with Xamarin.Forms and I have a doubt, could I do something like this  in a ListView?

[image: Delete Item from list View on left drag]

Comment: Yes it is possible using custom renderers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to achieve that.You will have to create custom renderers in order to do what you want. For iOS, the custom renderer would be done like in this post:
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/56693/#Comment_56693

For Android, it would be a little trickier as swiping listviews is not native, but perhaps you would either implement the OnFling method on your own, or maybe use a project like this one in a custom renderer:
https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

Also, here is a post that gives some insight into making custom renderers with gesture recognizers:
http://arteksoftware.com/gesture-recognizers-with-xamarin-forms/

You also could used `SfListView` to achieve that.
https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/swiping#swipe-customizations

There is GIF of running demo.

[image]